# Write username to a table from a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to write the user name who is currently logged in to records in the table X that is used to update table Y with new records from it.

Here is the code I use:

```
Private Sub UPD_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_UPD_Click

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", "D:\Working\Test.mdb", acTable, "tblTest", "tblTest_Import", False

DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE tblTest_Import ADD COLUMN [CreatedBy] Text(25);"

Dim myDB As Database
Set myDB = CurrentDb

myDB.Execute "UPDATE tblTest_Import " _
     & "SET [tblTest_Import].[CreatedBy] = [Forms]![frmLogin]![txtUserName];"

myDB.Execute "INSERT INTO tblMain(Year, CreatedBy)"_
     & "SELECT tblTest_Import.Year, tblTest_Import.CreatedBy " _
     & "FROM tblTest_Import " _
     & "WHERE (((Exists (SELECT * FROM tblMain " _
     & "WHERE tblMain.ID = tblTest_Import.ID))=False));"

Exit_UPD_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_UPD_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_UPD_Click

End Sub
```

Form frmLogin stays open but hidden (Me.Visible = False).

The problem is the field CreatedBy in tblTest_Import does not get updates and Access returns this message: "Too few parameters. Expected 1." And none of lines in the code gets highlighted.

I tried to add

```
Dim frmLogin As Form
Set frmLogin = Screen.ActiveForm
```

but it didn't help.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution :)

I just needed to add several quotes to this part of code

```
myDB.Execute "UPDATE tblTest_Import " _
     & "SET [tblTest_Import].[CreatedBy] = '" & [Forms]![frmLogin]![UserName] & "';"
```

Bingo!